# make redux toolkit query inside useEffect

Tags: api, redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I am receiving a cat prop and want to fetch data from api whenever cat is changed using RTK query. But it's getting error the following error:

`React Hook "useGetProductsQuery" cannot be called inside a callback".`

How to make a `RTK query` whenever `cat` is changed?

```
const Products = ({cat,filter,sort}) => {

const [products, setproducts] = useState([])

const [filters, setFilters] = useState([])

useEffect(()=>{

                const {data,isError,isLoading}=useGetProductsQuery()
                console.log(data,isError,isLoading)

         },[cat])
}


import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } 
from'@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';

const baseUrl=process.env.REACT_APP_ECOMMERCE_API_URL
const createRequest = (url) => ({ url });

export const ecommApi = createApi({
reducerPath: 'ecommApi',
baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({baseUrl}),
endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getProducts: builder.query({
        query: () => createRequest("/api/v1/products")
    }),
  })
})


export const{useGetProductsQuery}=ecommApi;
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not just pass `cat` as an argument to the `useQuery` hook without the `useEffect`?

That will make a new request every time `cat` changes.

```js
const {data,isError,isLoading}=useGetProductsQuery(cat)
```

Answer (score 2):

As an addition to phry's answer:

If "cat" might be undefined use the `skip` parameter for conditional fetching:

```
const {data,isError,isLoading} = useGetProductsQuery(cat, {skip: !cat})
```

See https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/conditional-fetching

Comment: how to handle more than one conditional fetching, suppose there are 2 arguments cat="footwear" and page=2. then how to fetch??

Comment: @RohitRai see the first example on https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/mutations